# What options are there for integrating with payment gateways?

Tags: ecommerce, payment-gateway

It seems that there are only two types of payment gateway service out there at the moment; Either that the entire cart logic is handled offsite (with something like Paypal's Standard option) or the other option being that you need to go through the certification for handling credit card numbers and doing pretty much everything yourself.

Ideally, for the project I'm working on, I'm after a bit of middle ground such that I can handle the cart on-site, and only pass over to a payment gateway (with an order amount, billing & delivery details, and order ref) for them to handle the card details, before passing back.

I'm sure that I've used e-commerce sites using this pattern before, but I cannot find any payment providers out there that offer this sort of option, so are there any? The only over requirement we have at present is that it must accept orders in Sterling.

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for or do you need some more answers?

Comment: @Christopher thanks for the poke -- I ended up using Google Checkout, which no-one else has mentioned, so I've added another answer :)

Comment: No problem, glad to see more people around here with some smarts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google checkout API](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API.html#checkout_api) offers that halfway house of being able to use your own custom cart, without having to actually go the whole hog and handle all the nuances of credit card number handling certification.

Answer (score 0):

I think most e-commerce providers have something like that, I use [FastSpring](http://fastspring.com) and they have an API where you can post the order details from your cart to their site where they handle the payment. (I think PayPal also have something similar but I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: That *looks like* the sort of thing I'm after, although they seem to only offer payments in USD, which would be a killer for me

Comment: @Rowland Shaw - They aren't USD only, they also support GBP (as well as EUR, AUD, CAD and JPY) - I'm not sure about all the details but you can just send them an e-mail, they are extremely responsive.

Comment: They talk about minimum account balances being $25 before paying, and also warn of bank charges for receiving funds via "international direct deposit" - it may just be badly worded, but it does put me off

Comment: @Rowland Shaw - banks charge you for everything, so do credit card companies and e-commerce providers - no money transfer is free - also, FastSpring are not the cheapest option - they are extremely good at what they do and have the best support I've ever seen - so I think they are worth every penny. now, if you don't expect to make $25 a month I don't think there's any payment solutions for you, with tiny sales the minimum charges will eat all your profits - you need to build your business first and get an e-commerce provider later (BTW, FastSpring can also send you the money via PayPal)

Comment: My point here is that I will get more preferable rates for transactions in Sterling.

Answer (score 0):

I still recommend using PayPal for your PayPal payment gateway as it is more accepted world-wide. Pleae do keep in mind that PayPal does not process payment from some countries yet (such as Egypt, and most of African countries).

If you believe you want to do business worldwide, this is something worth considering :-)